# Accessing Master page control in ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a master page file that contains a 2 menu's in a 2 panel controls.
I also use a control to check if user is logged in and get the type of user.

Deppending on the type I want to show / hide the panel. The control itself is not referenced in the master page but dynamically through the CMS System.

I want to use findcontrol in the user control to find the panel control in the master page. I have tried different methods but all come back with null.

The content placeholder in the master page is 
    asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PHMainBlock"

and the control is called
    asp:Panel ID="NormalUser" runat="server"

I have tried using the code....

```
Panel ph = (Panel)Page.Master.FindControl("NormalUser");
ph.Visible = false;
```

but brings back null, any help?

thanks..

Comment: Set the class name to your control and search it via class attribute ? Now register StartUp Script and access the function to do the same.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a public property in you Master Page i.e

```
public bool ShowPanel
{
    set
    {
        NormalUser.Visible = value;
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
if (Page.Master is NameOfMasterPage)
{
    ((NameOfMasterPage)Page.Master).ShowPanel = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the Panel control is inside a ContentPlaceHolder control, you must first get a reference to the ContentPlaceHolder and then use its FindControl method to locate the TextBox control.

```
ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
Panel pn;
mpContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("PHMainBlock");
if(mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
{
    pn = (Panel) mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("NormalUser");
    pn.Visible = false;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do something similar and it works fine:

```
if (Page.Master != null)
{
    var tempPanel = Page.Master.FindControl("MessagePanel") as UpdatePanel;
    if (tempPanel != null)
        tempPanel.Visible = true;


    var temp = Page.Master.FindControl("MessageForUser") as MessageToUser;
    if (temp != null)
        temp.PostWarningMessage(message, msgInterval);
}
```

However, I have "MessagePanel" and "MessageForUser" as controls right above the  ContentPlaceHolder.  Here's my markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" Visible="true" ID="MessagePanel" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <msg:MainMessage ID="MessageForUser" runat="server" Visible="true" />  
        <br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphContent" runat="server" Visible="true">              
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

If you have your Panel inside of a  tag, then you should be able to reference the panel without needing Page.Master.FindControl.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to solve this problem with javascript (jquery):

```
$('.NormalUser').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: This is not a good idea. First, it doesn't degrade for non-Javascript users. Second, even for Javascript users, it would expose in the source URLs that are not meant for the current user.