# Access variable from master page on ascx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have the following setup on an aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/tt.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="tt_login" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/tt.master" %>
```

and this on the aspx.cs page:

```
public partial class tt_login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected new ttUser User
    {
        get { return Master.User; }
        set { Master.User = value; }
    }
```

In this case, the the `ttUser` is able to access the variable from the master page.

All fine so far.

Next, I have an ascx page, with the following setup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/tt.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ttRightNav.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_ttRightNav" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/tt.master" %>
```

and on the same page:

```
protected new ###.##.ttUser User
{
    get { return Master.User; }
    set { Master.User = value; }
}
```

Only this time it says `the name master does not exist in the current context`

A far as I can see the setup is exactly the same- I cannot see why it is not working.

A couple of thoughts:

The ascx page is not in the root folder - but as it uses `~` it is referencing the root so this should not matter?

Is it because this is an ascx page?

Have I missed anything?

I have tried referencing the master variable from the ascx.cs page, but still have the same problem.

Basically, how can I reference a variable from the master page on an ascx page?

I have seen a few questions about casting from the master page,but so far have not been able to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am completely stuck!!!

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned above - the question above is about a control - I am trying to access an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Master page control in ascx file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315967/accessing-master-page-control-in-ascx-file)

Comment: @RB The question you reference is about a control in the master page - I am trying to access an object - find control will not work for me. Please read and understand the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make `ttuser` public
2. Try casting your Master Page to the specific class and then get the nedded fields

`tt_login loginPage = Page as tt_login;`

or

`tt_login loginPage = Master as tt_login;`