# access master page from ascx control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascx

I have a public property in a master page. I want to access this property from an ascx user control.

My master page is named master_public and it's in a namespace called "master".

So I tried writing:

```
dim m=ctype(page.master,master.master_public)
dim foobar=m.foobar
```

The intellisense says that master.master_public doesn't exist.

I tried removing the namespace from the master page. Still no luck.

The master page is declared "partial public class". But this name doesn't seem to be recognized.

Answers here [Accessing Master page control in ascx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315967/accessing-master-page-control-in-ascx-file) seem to imply that this should just ... work. Is there some attribute or setting or something I have to include to make master pages accessible as class types?

Comment: Try to redesign the control so it isn't tied to one particular master page. For example by injecting the required value into the control's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following on top of your form (.aspx):

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="master.master_public" %>
```

The above directive will expose public members of the masterpage to the form. To access your property from the form, simply reference as below:

```
Me.Master.YourProperty
```

Therefore, in order to access the masterpage public property from user controls added to the form, just cast the master page object :

```
CType(Me.Page.Master, master.master_public).YourProperty
```